# Looking for a more efficient way to filter out a perl hash

Tags: perl, hash

My goal is to remove from the *raw stack* the records that are *not* in the *good keys* list.

How do I achieve this in the most efficient manner? The code I'm currently working on feels dragging. I'm open for suggestions.

Please do note that the values could get ridiculously large.

Here's my data:

```
# Main data container
my %raw_stack = (
    'a1~a2~a3' => 'dat1~dat2',
    'b1~b2~b3' => 'dat1~dat2',
    'c1~c2~c3' => 'dat1~dat2',
    'd1~d2~d3' => 'dat1~dat2',
    'e1~e2~e3' => 'dat1~dat2',
);

# Container of stack keys only
my @stack_keys = (
    'a1~a2~a3',
    'b1~b2~b3',
    'c1~c2~c3',
    'd1~d2~d3',
    'e1~e2~e3',
);

# Container of valid keys
my @good_keys = (
    'a2',
    'c2',
    'e2',
);
```

Here's the code I'm currently working on:

```
foreach my $good_key (@good_keys)
{
    foreach my $stack_key (@stack_keys)
    {
        my @stack = split(/~/, $stack_key);
        if ($stack[1] eq $good_key)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I feel like there's a way to *not* need the stack keys container. I just don't know how...

Comment: (1) You don't need `@stack_keys` because you can just use `keys %raw_stack`. (2) Which approach is most efficient will depend on the sizes of these structures. If `@good_keys` is small, then it might make sense to convert it into a single regex that can be matched against each key in `%raw_stack`, whereas if it's big, then it would make more sense to express it as a lookup hash and perform `split`s as you are now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is that [favorite quote by Larry Wall](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Larry_Wall#1992): "Doing linear scans over an associative array is like trying to club someone to death with a loaded Uzi."

You should know about [hash slices](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices). With which you can do what's below. Of course that implies that you have a list of exact keys, which you don't. But to illustrate:

```
my %clean_hash;
@clean_hash{ @good_keys } = @raw_stack{ @good_keys };
```

However if you don't want to copy the values, you could do something a little more complicated like this:

```
delete @raw_stack{ grep { $_ !~~ @good_keys } keys %raw_stack };
```

This uses [smart matching](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Smart-matching-in-detail) from 5.10.

Of course you'll have to adapt from that. Assuming that you are only looking at the middle key `[1]`, it looks to me like you're looking for a *pattern* in a key, so create one.

```
my $regex = join( '|', sort { length( $b ) <=> length( $a ) or $a cmp $b } @good_keys );
$regex    = qr{~($regex)~};
delete @raw_stack{ grep { !m/$regex/ } keys %raw_stack };
```